# speed up looping through two dataframe cell by cell and find if one is part of the other

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have two big dataframe with size of 125*953 and 174*808. the total check takes round 30 mins and i want to speed it up.
this is a sample how my dataframes looks like:

```
   color material
0    red     wood
1   blue    metal
2  green  plastic


            name          description
0  my blue color  it is a great color
1      red chair       made with wood
2      green rod      made with metal
```

and i want to check every cell from the data if it has any word from the parameter dataframe cell by cell.

this is my current code.

```
import pandas as pd
import time
data = pd.read_csv('x.csv',converters={i: str for i in range(200)})
parameter = pd.read_excel('y.xlsx', sheet_name="Tags")

def extractData(i):
    for n in i:
        for row in parameter.columns:

            print(n.apply(lambda color: [c for c in parameter[row].tolist() if ( str(c)!='nan' and c in color)]))
s=time.time()
extractData([data[row] for row in  data.columns[3:4]  ] )
e=time.time()
print(e-s)
```

the output

```
       name           description            attribute  attribute2
0      my blue color  it is a great color    blue           
1      red chair      made with wood         red        wood
2      green rod      made with metal        green      metal
```

edit

```
parameter = pd.DataFrame({'color': ['red','blue','green','black','purple'],
                   'material': ['wood','metal','plastic','','']})


data = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['my blue metal color','red chair','green rod',' tree'],
                   'description': ['it is a great color','made with wood','','']})
data2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['my blue metal color ','red chair','green rod',' tree'],
                   'description': ['it is a great color','made with wood','','']})
```

edit2

```
parameter = pd.DataFrame({'color': ['red','blue','green','black','purple'],
                   'material': ['wood','metal','plastic','',''],
                        'w': ['reed','blue','green','black','purple']},)


data = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['my blue metal reed color','red chair','green rod',' tree'],
                   'description': ['it is a great color','made with wood','',''],})
for param, col in zip(parameter.columns, data.columns):
    words = set(parameter[param])
    data[param] = (data[col].str.split()
                       .apply(lambda x: ' '.join(words.intersection(x))))
```

Comment: What would you want the output to look like?

Comment: Check out pandas.DataFrame.applymap method if you want to apply a function to each element of the dataset.

Comment: i have update it

Comment: why the blue doesnt match ?

Comment: I dont care about the order of  th parameter. i just want to heck if they exist.

Comment: @Shatha updated my answer with a method that I think does what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I blew up `parameter` to be 90k distinct values, and `data` to be 180k rows. This whole thing runs in a matter of seconds.

```
# Split all words into lists.
data = data.apply(lambda x: x.str.split())

# Create sets for each parameter.
colors = set(parameter.color)
materials = set(parameter.material)

# Use set logic of `intersection` to find matching words.
data['color'] = data.name.apply(lambda x: colors.intersection(x))
data['material'] = data.description.apply(lambda x:materials.intersection(x))

# Change the lists back to strings.
data = data.apply(lambda x: x.str.join(' '))
```

Summarized to:

```
for param, col in zip(parameter.columns, data.columns):
    words = set(parameter[param])
    data[param] = (data[col].str.split()
                       .apply(lambda x: ' '.join(words.intersection(x))))
```

Output:

```
                 name          description  color material
0       my blue color  it is a great color   blue
1           red chair       made with wood    red     wood
2           green rod      made with metal  green    metal
3       my blue color  it is a great color   blue
4           red chair       made with wood    red     wood
...               ...                  ...    ...      ...
179995      red chair       made with wood    red     wood
179996      green rod      made with metal  green    metal
179997  my blue color  it is a great color   blue
179998      red chair       made with wood    red     wood
179999      green rod      made with metal  green    metal

[180000 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: I had a problem when the two dataframe dont have same size. can you please check it, it is edit 2

Comment: Do you want each column in `parameter` to be checked against the whole row in `data` or something? Your expected output, and the logic to get there, isn't very clear.

Comment: I want to check the color in both name and description a;so check the materials  in both name and description. please check edit 2

Answer (score 0):

You could craft a regex from the first dataframe, then use it to search the values:

```
import re

regex = '|'.join(map(re.escape, df1.stack().drop_duplicates()))
# 'red|wood|blue|metal|green|plastic'

out = (df2.stack().str.extractall(f'({regex})')[0]
          .groupby(level=[0,1]).agg(list)
          .unstack(fill_value=[])
       )
```

Output:

```
  description     name
0          []   [blue]
1      [wood]    [red]
2     [metal]  [green]
```

Alternative output:

```
import re

regex = '|'.join(map(re.escape, df1.stack().drop_duplicates()))
# 'red|wood|blue|metal|green|plastic'

out = (df2
 .stack()
 .str.extractall(f'({regex})')
 .reset_index()
 .assign(col=lambda d: d.groupby('level_0').cumcount().add(1))
 .pivot('level_0', 'col', 0)
 .add_prefix('attribute').rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
 )
```

Output:

```
  attribute1 attribute2
0       blue        NaN
1        red       wood
2      green      metal
```

Comment: You should provide a reproducible test dataframe. How much does it slow it?

Comment: THe speed is great now. really rhanl you for your help.

Comment: is there anyway to get  which value for which key. So i can seperate color and materials in different colomn.  I have updated the code.

Comment: Then just two regexes and merge in the end

Comment: I'm on my phone, I can't update a large piece, let me see if I can give it a try later